# Exception on actionPerformed button

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

This is a swing window under construction. The problem is in an Action. 
When I have an action on "open" button , I call a method `OpenFile()`.

This method seems to work until the end where it throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` ,exception.

```
import static alphareader.AlphaReaderBackup.maxGap;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;


public class AlphaReader extends JFrame 
implements ActionListener {

    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

    private final JButton open=new JButton("Open File.");
    private final JButton exitButton = new JButton(" Exit ");

    JLabel welcomeMsg=new JLabel("Welcome to alpha reader. ");


    //BoxLayout boxy = new BoxLayout();
    GridLayout gridy = new GridLayout(3,2);
    FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
    GridLayout rowsGrid=new GridLayout();


    Dimension btn=new Dimension(132,32);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        AlphaReader alpha=new AlphaReader();
        alpha.setSize(800,800);
        alpha.createGui();
        alpha.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createGui(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container window=getContentPane();
    window.setLayout(gridy);
    JPanel row1=new JPanel();
    JPanel row2=new JPanel();
    JPanel row3=new JPanel();


    window.add(row1);
    row1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(flow.LEFT,10,10));
    row1.add(welcomeMsg); 
    welcomeMsg.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,32));
    welcomeMsg.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    row1.add(open);
    open.setPreferredSize(btn);
    open.addActionListener(this);
    exitButton.setPreferredSize(btn);
    row1.add(exitButton);
    exitButton.addActionListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
    Object source = new Object();
    source=ev.getSource();
    if(source==open){
        openFile();
    }
        else if(source==exitButton){
                System.exit(0);
                }
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    private void openFile(){
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(AlphaReader.this);
        //fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();} //I get the exception here.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
Object source = new Object();
source=ev.getSource();
if(source==open){
    openFile();
}
else if(source==exitButton){
    System.exit(0);
}
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
```

to

```
JButton source = (JButton) ev.getSource();
if(source == open){
    openFile();
}
else if(source == exitButton){
    System.exit(0);
}
else
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
```

Without the `else` statement, an `UnsupportedOperationException` will always be thrown.

Comment: You're welcome. Plus, I think you should be comparing same references in your `if/else` statements, in order for this to work. (The small change I made on top)

Comment: I write in C++.Now I am trying to learn Java.I make the correction as you propose.Thank you very much for your time.However I cant understand why you do this.   PS:My grandmother was born in Sparta.  :)

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis you're welcome. Look, in order to compare references, they sould be the same. For the example, you can't do something like `String s; int i; if(s == i) { }` because a `String` cannot be an `int`.

Comment: You are right thats obvious.I manipulate JComponents as Objects in general.Probably its a very bad strategy.Thanx a lot

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis you are welcome & good luck ! (***PS: This is Sparta !***)